# Theoretical sequence: how is a .jar file created?

Tags: java, jar

How are `.jar`s created?

I know that an IDE like Eclipse can create Bytecode (.class) from developed Sourcecode (.java). And it can under "Export" create an .jar.

And know i want to know: Is an .jar created:

- direct from Sourcecode?
- from Bytecode which was copied?
- with a totally other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code files (`.java` files) are compiled to [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) by [Java Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler). Bytecode is then stored in `.class` files.

These files are then packed together using [jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) tool to create JAR (**Java Archive**) file. JAR file is a *zip archive* usually containing:

- `.class` files,
- [jar manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)
- application resources

You can read more about Jar files on oficial documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Answer (score 0):

A `.jar` is just an archive of `.class` files along with associated resources (if any) and metadata (if any). In fact, "jar" means **J**ava **AR**chive, and the file format is the same as .zip files. From the [Oracle JAR file overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jarGuide.html) :

> JAR consists of a zip archive, as defined by PKWARE, containing a manifest file and potentially signature files, as defined in the [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).

So source code is compiled to `.class` files (bytecode) which is then wrapped up in a `.jar` archive via the `jar` tool (or anything else that can correctly create `.jar` files per the spec).

Comment: @AndyTurner: Yeah, I wasn't going to go there, but I suppose it's harmless.